# Internet Explorer: Bad visualization of CSS Table (table-row, table-cell)

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, css-tables

I've made a CSS table structure using display table, table-row and table cell properties.

Each p has table-row property and they jump line OK. But when I put 2 o more elements (input or select) in the same **`<p>`** I would like that this elements were inline but in IE (last version) jump of line in spite of to belong to he same **`<p>`**

Is there any solution to fix this? The perfect visualization is like Firefox, all elements in line.

```
<p><label>Name (first, second): </label><input type="text" /><input type="text" /></p>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HY62t/

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following Class in your CSS.

```
 fieldset input{display:inline-block}
```

It will resolve your issue and display properly in all the browsers.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/HY62t/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: top` (and `padding-top`) or `middle` to `labels`.

In case of two inputs on separate lines zou can use for example `fieldset input {float: left;}`.

Comment: I need the elements in line, not the label on top. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer. But you have problem with labels too, or not (in IE the labels are lower than should be). First time, I didn´t see you have broken input :-)

Comment: `float: left` breaks the table structure. Any example?

Comment: Ah, sorry. So, `display: inline` can help you. Why don't you use table if you want to make table-view? It'd be easier.

Comment: In this case, I need only CSS table. `display: inline` breaks the size of table columns.